# Set height div same as other div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've seen alot of questions on this topic, but none work for me. Display: flex; does do the trick but removes the float on divs.  I don't want to use table-cells either.

The image div has to scale in height depending on the heigh of the div with text. it looks fine the way it does now, but when you resize it or add alot more text it pulls the div out of proportion.

I don't mind using either CSS or js.

```
    <div class="content">
    <div class="productcol">
        <div class="productimg right" style="background-image:url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/8704/pen-idea-bulb-paper.jpg'); background-size:cover; background-position:center center;"></div>
        <div class="producteentweede">
            <div class="producttext  left">
                 <h3>Title</h3>

                <p>Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper.

Donec sed odio dui. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



.content {
    width: 92%;
    max-width: 76em;
    padding: 0 4%;
    margin: auto;
}


.productcol{
    width:100%;
    margin-left:0;
    display:block;  
}

.producteen{
    width:100%;
    height:30em;
}

.producteentweede, .productimg{
    width:50%;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    min-height:30em;
}

.producttext{
    padding-left:2em;
    padding-right:2em;
    margin-top:5em;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m6s0xhw6/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I've had help from a friendly mastermind and got it working!

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$( window ).resize(function() {
    resizeToTextHeight();
});

$(function() {
    resizeToTextHeight();
});

function resizeToTextHeight(){
    $('.productcol').each(function(i, obj) {
        var height = $(this).find(".producteentweede").height();
        $(this).find(".productimg").css("min-height", height);
    });
}};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way for setting one elements height corresponding to others height.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').height($('.text-div').outerHeight());
});
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me :/ I changed it to this:
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.producttextJS').height($('.productimgJS').outerHeight());
});

Comment: There is a mistake - the image should have a height equal to the text div so: $('.productimgJS').height($('.producttextJS').outerHeight()); }); Also do you have any errors in the console? Click f12 and go to Console and see for red errors.